# Get the month of a date with addAttributeToFilter

Tags: magento, collections

Is it possible to get the month of a date with addAttributeToFilter? I need to get the month of the date of birth of some clients, but nothing is working. I'm trying the code bellow:

```
<?php

$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')->setOrder('firstname', 'ASC')->addAttributeToFilter('dob', array('like'=>'03'));

foreach ($collection as $client) { 

      echo  $client->getSelect()." ". $client->getData('firstname')." ".$client->getData('lastname')."<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php$collection
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('dob', array('like'=>'%03%'))
            ->setOrder('firstname', 'ASC');

foreach ($collection as $client) { 

      echo  $client->getData('firstname')." ".$client->getData('lastname')."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: with this I will get the same result.

Comment: try like this `->addAttributeToFilter('dob', array('like'=>'%03%'))`

Comment: so, as I told when you answered this before, these wildcards filters the date which has an '03' on a date composition, i mean it doesn't care if the '03' is in a day or month or year, do you know if we can filter only the '03' when it is in a month?

Comment: I got it! It's like this `->addAttributeToFilter('dob', array('like'=>'%-03-%'))` Thanks for your help!